# How can I extend scala.collection.mutable.Map when it is abstract?

Tags: scala, class, abstract, extend

I'm trying to extend `scala.collection.mutable.Map`. I'm looking at https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html . Documentation says class is abstract. Yet I can instantiate a mutable Map like

```scala
val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]()
```

I'm confused as to what is going on here and how to implement missing methods in my derived class.

Comment: Because this: `scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]()` is not calling a **constructor** is calling the `apply` method on the `mutable.Map`  **companion object**... why do you need / want to extend the `Map` class?

Comment: I need a fancy update function, something like outlined in this study https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hyperchessbot/2CBrdmBwSlyfVdIZKnTKuw/27

Comment: And do you really need to override `apply`? or can you live with just an **extension method**? And do you need it to be mutable? - Also, BTW, your custom `apply` looks the [**Monoid**](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monoid.html) of `Map`.

Comment: not exactly, I want update to delete the key, if I pass None ( rather than having a value None in the map ), and it actually does this, here is my improved version where I package the whole thing into a case class ( better than nothing, but not real inheritance ) https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hyperchessbot/2CBrdmBwSlyfVdIZKnTKuw/76

Comment: You didn't add it as part of your question, so I didn't add it to my answer, but you can create such a method: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/39ow51mSRi6g51EtbcjG7Q/1

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `Map` extends `MapFactory.Delegate[Map](HashMap)`. You can see it [Scala source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/Map.scala#L228):

```scala
object Map extends MapFactory.Delegate[Map](HashMap) {
```

In `MapFactory.Delegate` there is an [`apply` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Factory.scala#L439), which is the one you call (the first method in this class):

```
class Delegate[C[_, _]](delegate: MapFactory[C]) extends MapFactory[C] {
  override def apply[K, V](elems: (K, V)*): C[K, V] = delegate.apply(elems: _*)
  def from[K, V](it: IterableOnce[(K, V)]): C[K, V] = delegate.from(it)
  def empty[K, V]: C[K, V] = delegate.empty
  def newBuilder[K, V]: Builder[(K, V), C[K, V]] = delegate.newBuilder
}
```

From your comments, it seems like you want to implement a custom update. You can try this function:

```scala
def customUpdate[K](m: mutable.Map[K, Int], key: K, value: Option[Int]): Unit = {
  value.fold {
    m.remove(key)
  } { newValue =>
    m.updateWith(key) {
      case None =>
        Some(newValue)
      case Some(currentValue) =>
        Some(currentValue + newValue)
    }
  }
}
```

which created the expected output as in your comments. Code run in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/39ow51mSRi6g51EtbcjG7Q/1).